# How to chose best coin flipping machine?

Tags: normal-distribution

How to chose best coin flipping machine ?

On job interview I was asked to solve the following problem.
There is some amount of different coins, some are fair and some are not. Also there are two coin flipping machines. As a result of several coin flipping experiments a table reflecting machine outcomes was created.
Also a person was asked to flip the same coins and his outcomes were added to the same table. Resulting table has the the following format:

```
Coin Id | Flip cnt | P hds | P tls | M1 hds | M1 tls | M2 hds | M2 tls
```

where:
P hds - count of heads flipped by Person
P tls - count of tails flipped by Person
M1 hds - count of heads flipped by Machine 1
M1 tls - count of tails flipped by Machine 1 
M2 hds - count of heads flipped by Machine 2
M2 tls - count of tails flipped by Machine 2

Question:
How to determine machine that is better to use for flipping coins using data in this table? 
As I understood at the interview a "better" machine in this context is the one that has coin flipping closer to normal distribution.

Any ideas how to solve this task?

Comment: Coin flips don't have a normal distribution. If you count the number of heads, they're usually modelled as having a binomial distribution. (But maybe 'better' just means 'gets a greater proportion of heads'; did they clearly specify or was that just your guess?)

Comment: As we make more and more flips, the graph of the probability of a given number of heads becomes smoother and approaches the “bell curve”, or normal distribution, as a limit. At the interview they just asked "how to chose a better flipping machine ?" As I understand, using the experiment data in the table, I had to find machine more immune to coins that are not fair.

Comment: Yes, I know what it approaches as a limit; if we're going to be technical about it, it's actually the standardized number of heads that approaches a limiting distribution ... but in any case, that's not what you said before and the difference can matter. [By the way, if it had been me at the interview, my first response would likely have been 'define better in this context'. Much better to ask what might be a slightly dumb question, and be sure what question you're supposed to be answering.]

Comment: I think the interview question can be formulated as: "Using the experimental data in the table, find which coin  flipping machine is "more immune" to coins that are not fair." How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to comparatively evaluate two entities, we need an evaluation criterion. In general, we would want to check whether the two machines are "fair", and in comparative terms, which one is "fairer" than the other. So if the "optimal" would be that each machine functions as though giving 50-50 chance to heads/tails, we would compare the empirical relative frequencies, against the $(\frac 12 , \frac 12)$ ideal situation. Problem is, *our coins are not all fair*. So I suppose that *the flippings by the person should now function as the evaluation criterion*. Namely, we would obtain the empirical frequencies from the human flippings, accept them as representing "the" distribution implied by the fair and unfair coins together, and then compare pairwise the empirical frequencies from the two machines against the human ones, by some distance measure like for example the [Hellinger distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance). The machine with the smaller distance from the human flippings, could then be chosen as the one representing better the biased structure of the coins.  I don't see how the normal distribution fits the picture, the comments regarding limiting behavior notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed comment. At the interview I proposed to calculate MSE (Mean Squared Error) to estimate differences between human frequencies and machine frequencies. Machine with smaller MSE I suggested to be a more realistic coin flipper. The interviewer said that my idea is "at least some solution", yet not a good one, as I concluded from his words. Why Hellinger distance is better the MSE?

Comment: To say that the one is "better" than the other, one should investigate exhaustively how they perform under various scenaria. In fact the _square_ of the Hellinger distance looks "a lot" like an MSE formula. I guess your interviewer had in mind that the MSE is a "forecasting performance" measure, not a "distribution similarity" measure, and this may have unduly affected his on-the-spot comment. If you look at the Hellinger distance wiki page, you will see the similarities with the MSE.